# Manipulating an expression into the form I want

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression arising from a physics problem:`(c Sqrt[-me^2 + mr^2])/mr`, where `c`, `me`, and `mr` are all positive. I want to direct Mathematica to give the expression below;
`c Sqrt[1 - (me/mr)^2] ;` Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: `expr = c  Sqrt[mr^2 - me^2]/mr; (expr /. me -> t*mr // Simplify[#, mr > 0] &) /. t -> me/mr`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a specific rule is all what is needed to force what you want. ofcourse, this assumes the math is correct but since you said they are all positive, then this is OK.

```
e1 = c  Sqrt[-me^2 + mr^2]/mr 
e1 /. any_.*Sqrt[b_]/c_ :> Simplify[any*Sqrt[b/c^2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`FullSimplify` with assumptions did not do it.  not sure why, since leaf count of the final result you wanted is 16 while leave count of the original expression is 18, so I expected it to have worked but it did not simplify it.

```
e1 = c  Sqrt[-me^2 + mr^2]/mr 
LeafCount[e1]
(* 18 *)

e2 = c*Sqrt[1 - (me/mr)^2]
LeafCount[e2]
(* 16 *)

 Assuming[{c > 0, me > 0, mr > 0}, FullSimplify[e1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So when all else fails, make your own rule. Just make sure the Pattern Rule is mathematically valid to apply.

Comment: perhaps changing the ComplexityFunction to put more weight on LeafCount?

Comment: @CraigCarter that is possibility, I have not tried it,  but I find just making a simple rule like in this case, is easier most of the time than dealing with complexityFunction.